# How to effectively convert between NSNumber and NSString objects

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `NSDictionary` object and there are hundreds of key-object pair in it. All objects are either `NSNumber` or `NSString`.

Check this :

```
NSDictionary *dic = 
{
@"item1" : a NSNumber object, 
@"item2" : a NSString object,
@"item3" : a NSString object,
....
}
```

I'd like to convert this `NSDictionary` to a model class with same key, but assigned type as :

```
@interface ClassA 
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *item1; 
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *item2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *item3;
....
```

Is there an effective way to do this? I have tried key-value-coding ...

```
ClassA *class = [Class new];
 [dic enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop){
    [class setValue:obj forKey:key];
 }
```

But what happen is item1 is still NSNumber, and item2 is still NSString..

Need some guidance on this.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "one-by-one"?  In the end you will have to examine each one if that's what you mean.  Whether or not you write them out one by one is a different story

Comment: KVC should do it, however it's unclear why the keys/properties would be a different type in the dictionary compared to the custom object?

Comment: Dictionary is parsed from some private API. Some value should be double. But it returns string back.

Comment: @borrrden , I do want to find a way without re-check the property. I found a potential solution. But not sure if it works yet.. will post here later

Comment: This way of doing things is utterly silly.  It is still unclear to me why you need to transform things this way.  However, what you can do is use `isKindOfClass` to test the return type of the class (using `getValueForKey`) against the type of the obj, and convert as necessary.

Comment: On my later project I use jsonModel..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was raised when parsing data from server and imported them to app Model. Data sometimes just incorrect and I won't be able to correct the source right away. So I hope to have a way to compare parsed object and model property type. If they does not match, model will automatically convert the parsed object into correct type.

To get the model class property type, we can use

```
unsigned int outCount, i;
objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList(klass, &outCount);
```

for each property in properties, we can get its name and type

```
NSString *propertyName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:property_getName(property)];
NSString *propertyType = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:getPropertyType(property)];
```

Then we can compare the property with parsed data

Answer (score 0):

I Hope this helps:

```
[dict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id object, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"%@ = %@", key, object);
    NSString *Key = [key stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0,1)
                                                           withString:[[key substringToIndex:1] capitalizedString]];
    SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"[self set%@ = %@]",Key, object]);
    [class performSelector:selector];
}];
```

Comment: this just like KVC. Item1 will be still NSNumber. It will crash when you call some method can't find in NSNnumber